# Array prototype method: Can `this` ever be `null`?

Tags: javascript, null, prototype, this, polyfills

I'm looking at the `Array.prototype.includes` [Polyfill, as shown on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#Polyfill).
There's a few lines at the top that don't make much sense to me:

```
// https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.includes
if (!Array.prototype.includes) {
  Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'includes', {
    value: function(searchElement, fromIndex) {

      // 1. Let O be ? ToObject(this value).
      if (this == null) {
        throw new TypeError('"this" is null or not defined');
      }
```

Specifically, the `this == null` check there.

#### How can `this` be `null` (or even falsy) there? How can that condition ever be true?

As far as I know there isn't a single falsy value that you could invoke `.includes` on, since even an empty array is truthy.
I'm sure there's a good reason for the `null` check being there, but what could it be?

The [spec linked in the polyfill](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.includes) doesn't explicitly state any `null` check requirement.

---

For completeness' sake, here's the complete polyfill:

```js
// https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.includes
if (!Array.prototype.includes) {
  Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'includes', {
    value: function(searchElement, fromIndex) {

      // 1. Let O be ? ToObject(this value).
      if (this == null) {
        throw new TypeError('"this" is null or not defined');
      }

      var o = Object(this);

      // 2. Let len be ? ToLength(? Get(O, "length")).
      var len = o.length >>> 0;

      // 3. If len is 0, return false.
      if (len === 0) {
        return false;
      }

      // 4. Let n be ? ToInteger(fromIndex).
      //    (If fromIndex is undefined, this step produces the value 0.)
      var n = fromIndex | 0;

      // 5. If n ≥ 0, then
      //  a. Let k be n.
      // 6. Else n < 0,
      //  a. Let k be len + n.
      //  b. If k < 0, let k be 0.
      var k = Math.max(n >= 0 ? n : len - Math.abs(n), 0);

      function sameValueZero(x, y) {
        return x === y || (typeof x === 'number' && typeof y === 'number' && isNaN(x) && isNaN(y));
      }

      // 7. Repeat, while k < len
      while (k < len) {
        // a. Let elementK be the result of ? Get(O, ! ToString(k)).
        // b. If SameValueZero(searchElement, elementK) is true, return true.
        // c. Increase k by 1. 
        if (sameValueZero(o[k], searchElement)) {
          return true;
        }
        k++;
      }

      // 8. Return false
      return false;
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I got it

```
(function() {
  "use strict";

  if (!Array.prototype.includes2) {
  Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'includes2', {
    value: function(searchElement, fromIndex) {

      // 1. Let O be ? ToObject(this value).
      if (this == null) {
        throw new TypeError('"this" is null or not defined');
      }

      var o = Object(this);

      // 2. Let len be ? ToLength(? Get(O, "length")).
      var len = o.length >>> 0;

      // 3. If len is 0, return false.
      if (len === 0) {
        return false;
      }

      // 4. Let n be ? ToInteger(fromIndex).
      //    (If fromIndex is undefined, this step produces the value 0.)
      var n = fromIndex | 0;

      // 5. If n ≥ 0, then
      //  a. Let k be n.
      // 6. Else n < 0,
      //  a. Let k be len + n.
      //  b. If k < 0, let k be 0.
      var k = Math.max(n >= 0 ? n : len - Math.abs(n), 0);

      function sameValueZero(x, y) {
        return x === y || (typeof x === 'number' && typeof y === 'number' && isNaN(x) && isNaN(y));
      }

      // 7. Repeat, while k < len
      while (k < len) {
        // a. Let elementK be the result of ? Get(O, ! ToString(k)).
        // b. If SameValueZero(searchElement, elementK) is true, return true.
        // c. Increase k by 1. 
        if (sameValueZero(o[k], searchElement)) {
          return true;
        }
        k++;
      }

      // 8. Return false
      return false;
    }
  });
}
})();
```

And then

```
console.log(Array.prototype.includes2.call(null));
// Uncaught TypeError: "this" is null or not defined
```

---

MDN. Strict mode. "Securing" JavaScript: ([link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode))

> For a normal function, `this` is always an object: either the provided
>   object if called with an object-valued `this`; the value, boxed, if
>   called with a Boolean, string, or number `this`; or the global object if
>   called with an undefined or null `this`...
>   Thus for a strict mode function, the specified `this` is not boxed into
>   an object, and if unspecified, `this` will be undefined.

Comment: So, _"strict mode"_ makes that happen? Can you tell me why?

Comment: @Cerbrus I updated the answer with an MDN blockqute.

Comment: Ah, that explains what's happening. Thanks.